# Can someone tell me why I am getting this error, is it because of the spacing (I know quotations matter)?

Tags: postgresql, macos

```
create table product(
productid int, 
description varchar(20)
);
 insert into product ( productid, description ) Values ( 42 , ' tv');
ERROR:  column "description" of relation "product" does not exist
```

Comment: Your posted code contains Unicode Line-Separator characters within the SQL syntax. I don't believe that Postgres supports this (or if it does, you need to ensure your tooling and connection to Postgres is fully Unicode-aware). That said, the Unicode Line-Separator character is hardly ever used (whereas everyone in the world uses ASCII `\r\n`). What localization settings are on your computer?

Comment: I do not understand most of what you asked sorry. Could you rephrase your question.

Comment: I'll ask a different question: how did you write that SQL code (or did you copy it from somewhere else)? and what program are you using to run it?

Comment: I copied it from text edit(MAC), but I wrote in the insert statement.

Comment: Please answer my second question.

Comment: What i used is Postgresql

Comment: **Postgres is a headless server**, it isn't a desktop GUI program like MS Word and you can't directly use Postgres so you need a client program to actually execute queries and statements. Are you using Postgres' command-line client `psql`, a web-based admin tool (like `phpPgAdmin`), a desktop admin tool like SQL Workbench, or something else?

Comment: I am using the command-line

Comment: Whatever character you have before the `insert`, `productid`, `description` and `values` isn't valid in SQL. There is no need for anything there (although a space would make it readable). Remove whatever noise that is to fix your code.

Comment: Im confused I do not have any characters before them, its just space, no other words or characters just space.

Comment: I suggest you open this StackOverflow question on a non-Apple/non-Mac computer - or paste your query into a hex editor - as those will show the invalid characters. If you're using TextEdit on a Mac then make sure it's in "Plain text" mode rather than the normal mode otherwise you'll find yourself getting your SQL code unintentionally autocorrected into something that really isn't SQL because TextEdit will convert your ASCII quotes, commas and dots into _pretentious punctuation_ characters.

Comment: I do not have a non apple/mac computer, but what is a hex editor and where can i get one. Question why isn't my code working if i type it in directly into the command line without copying and pasting?

Comment: It doesn't work because you're not using TextEdit in Plaintext mode: https://www.iphonehacks.com/2017/06/plain-text-mode-textedit-mac.html

Comment: I converted it and I am still getting an error: Insert into customer (customerid, username, fname, lname, street1, street2, city, state, zip )Values ( 42, ‘guitarhero’, ‘wes','mongtomery',’123mainstreet', 'NA’ ,' NYC’ ,’NY ', 10 );
IIt i snot showing that it is working.

Answer (score 1):

As several people pointed out in comments, there are invisible characters (sometimes called "gremlins") in your SQL that make it invalid. Here's a hex dump of the contents (after copying the code from the question, using macOS commands):

```
$ pbpaste | xxd -g1
00000000: 63 72 65 61 74 65 20 74 61 62 6c 65 20 70 72 6f  create table pro
00000010: 64 75 63 74 28 0a 70 72 6f 64 75 63 74 69 64 20  duct(.productid 
00000020: 69 6e 74 2c e2 80 a8 0a 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74  int,....descript
                      ^^ ^^ ^^                                 ^^^
00000030: 69 6f 6e 20 76 61 72 63 68 61 72 28 32 30 29 0a  ion varchar(20).
00000040: 29 3b 0a e2 80 a8 69 6e 73 65 72 74 20 69 6e 74  );....insert int
00000050: 6f 20 70 72 6f 64 75 63 74 20 28 e2 80 a8 70 72  o product (...pr
00000060: 6f 64 75 63 74 69 64 2c e2 80 a8 64 65 73 63 72  oductid,...descr
                                  ^^ ^^ ^^                         ^^^

00000070: 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 20 29 e2 80 a8 56 61 6c 75 65  iption )...Value
                                  ^^ ^^ ^^                         ^^^
00000080: 73 20 28 20 34 32 20 2c 20 27 20 74 76 27 29 3b  s ( 42 , ' tv');
00000090: 0a 45 52 52 4f 52 3a 20 20 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 20  .ERROR:  column 
000000a0: 22 64 65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e 22 20 6f 66  "description" of
000000b0: 20 72 65 6c 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 22 70 72 6f 64 75   relation "produ
000000c0: 63 74 22 20 64 6f 65 73 20 6e 6f 74 20 65 78 69  ct" does not exi
000000d0: 73 74                                            st
```

(Note that `xxd` represents bytes that don't correspond to printable ASCII characters as "." in the text display on the right. The "."s that correspond to 0a in hex are newline characters.)

The hex codes e2 80 a8 correspond to the UTF-8 encoding of the [unicode "line separator" character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm). I don't know how that character got in there; you'd have to trace back the origin of that code snippet to figure out where they were added.

I'd avoid using TextEdit for source code (and config files, etc) . Instead, I'd recommend using [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) or some other code-oriented editor. I think even in BBEdit's free-demo mode it can show (and let you remove) normally-invisible characters by choosing View menu -> Text Display -> Show Invisibles.

You can also remove non-plain-ASCII characters from a text file from the macOS Terminal with:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -d '\n\t -~' <infile.txt >cleanfile.txt
```

(Replacing `infile.txt` and `cleanfile.txt` with the paths/names of the input file and where you want to store the output.) Warning: do *not* try to write the cleaned contents back to the original file, that won't work. Also, don't use this to clean anything except plain text files (if the file has any sections that aren't supposed to be text sections, this may mangle those sections). Keep the original file as a backup until you've verified that the "clean" version works right.

You can also "clean" the paste buffer with:

```
pbpaste | LC_ALL=C tr -d '\n\t -~' | pbcopy
```

...so just copy the relevant code from your text editor, run that in Terminal, then paste the cleaned version back into the editor.

Comment: Thank you so much that helped a lot, where would I type that line of LC_ALL in. Also when I type the code directly into my command-line I am still having error messages.                             
      insert into customer
(
customerid,
username,
fname,
lname,
street1,
street2,
city,
state,
zip
)
Values(42, 'guitarhero', 'wes', 'montgomery', 'mainstreet', 'broadway','manhattan', 'NY', 112304);

Comment: @brandker Just enter it in the normal Terminal shell interface; the only tricky thing is replacing the path/filename placeholders I used with the actual paths. If you aren't comfortable with that, I added a version that cleans the pasteboard. Or just use BBEdit, show invisibles, and delete the weird characters there.

Comment: ok ill try it thanks